# How to click a link on webpage C#

Tags: c#

Here is the code on the webpage:

```
<div id="dl_link" style="display: block;">
<a href="/get?video_id=KMU0tzLwhbE&h=3713fa1cb8c500381a1edaaf80a06ab5">
<b>Download</b>
```

but I do not know how to code the click of that link in c#.

This is pretty much what I have so far;

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("youtube-url").SetAttribute("value", textBox1.Text); // put text into textbox
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submit").InvokeMember("onclick"); // click convert video button
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlElement downloadlink = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("href="); //wrong
    downloadlink.InvokeMember("onclick"); //wrong
}
```

I am totally lost on how to perform the last step. Please help.

Comment: sent HTTP GET to the underlying url

Comment: Is this some kind of XY Problem? http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341

Comment: Once it's been rendered to the client, server-side ASP.Net code *can't* click the link.  What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why this question got downvoted? It is a valid question about `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` (or at least I think so) and has nothing to do with ASP.NET.

Comment: I agree - it's a totally valid and useful question.

Comment: @MikeGoodwin This is just a guess, but it seems PO wants to download/play a video, Trying to achieve this with those `link clicks` is not a good way. See my XY Problem link.

Comment: @L.B, you could be right

Answer (score 1):

Since your link is just an ordinary link, with no JS code attached, you can use `webBrowser1.Navigate(downloadlink.GetAttribute("href"));`;

**Edit:** To get `downloadlink` use `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("dl_link").All[0]`

Comment: It may be that the link has some event handlers attached dynamically from javascript that is not obvious from the page source, in which case, this solution could cause problems. Maybe better to use HtmlElement.RaiseEvent(), but I've never done that so don't want to post as an answer :o)

Comment: If there would be any `onclick` handler on that link set from external script, `InvokeMember("click")` or `RaiseEvent` would have worked, but Andrew wrote that it didn't.

Comment: Good point. In any case, after looking into it RaiseEvent() will not work either. It only causes event handlers defined in javascript to get called - very similar to InvokeMember() so your answer is the best.

Answer (score 0):

You could automate it using [WatiN](http://watin.org/) if you aren't overly concerned with performance.

```
using (var browser = new IE("http://stackoverflow.com")){
    var link = browser.Divs.First(Find.ById("dl_link")).Links.First();
    link.Click(;
}
```